# GO resty equivalent to the below CURL command

Tags: go, curl

So, I have a curl command that works just fine. But, when I try to implement it in [Resty](https://github.com/go-resty/resty) I get an error: 405 (method not allowed). Now, that error code shouldn't be taken too seriously. Just an indication I am doing something wrong.

The curl command that works like a champ does this:

```sh
christianb@christianb-mac hashicorp % curl -vn --location --request PUT 'http://localhost:8081/artifactory/example-repo-local/crash.zip' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/zip' \
--data-binary '@./samples/crash.zip'
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:8081...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8081 (#0)
* Server auth using Basic with user 'admin'
> PUT /artifactory/example-repo-local/crash.zip HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8081
> Authorization: Basic xxx=
> User-Agent: curl/7.78.0
> Accept: */*
> Content-Type: application/zip
> Content-Length: 0
> 
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 201 
< X-JFrog-Version: Artifactory/7.24.3 72403900
< X-Artifactory-Id: 65b0c15e32af425b:-53411fa9:17be4f9b6e8:-8000
< X-Artifactory-Node-Id: cb4b887aed9e
< Location: http://localhost:8081/artifactory/example-repo-local/crash.zip
< X-Checksum-Sha256: e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855
< Content-Type: application/vnd.org.jfrog.artifactory.storage.ItemCreated+json;charset=ISO-8859-1
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Date: Wed, 15 Sep 2021 21:22:56 GMT
< 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      christianb@christianb-mac hashicorp %
```

And the resty call looks like this:

```
PUT /artifactory/example-local-repo/crash.zip HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1
User-Agent: jfrog/terraform-provider-artifactory:2.3.1
Content-Length: 4007
Accept: */*
Authorization: Basic cccxxx=
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=a8cddfc21bc1ecdf09e0c82e2e0ea2ac7627c4cbfeae3e51ed9e68987a99
Accept-Encoding: gzip

--a8cddfc21bc1ecdf09e0c82e2e0ea2ac7627c4cbfeae3e51ed9e68987a99
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="crash.zip"; filename="../../samples/crash.zip"
Content-Type: application/zip

...
HTTP/1.1 405 
X-JFrog-Version: Artifactory/7.24.3 72403900
X-Artifactory-Id: 65b0c15e32af425b:-53411fa9:17be4f9b6e8:-8000
X-Artifactory-Node-Id: cb4b887aed9e
Allow: OPTIONS, GET, HEAD, POST
Content-Type: application/json;charset=ISO-8859-1
Content-Length: 65
Date: Wed, 15 Sep 2021 21:41:07 GMT

{
  "errors" : [ {
    "status" : 405,
    "message" : ""
  } ]
}
```

So, clearly resty is treating this as a multi-part upload, which is wrong.

Does anyone know the equivalent resty call to this curl command?

I've tried:

```golang
    uri := "/artifactory/" + remotePath
    reader, err := os.Open(localPath)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    _, err = client.R().SetBody(reader).
        SetHeader("Content-Type", contentType).Put(uri)
```

and

```golang
    _, err = client.R().SetFileReader(filepath.Base(localPath), localPath, reader).
        SetHeader("Content-Type", contentType).Put(uri)
```

and

```golang
    uri := "/artifactory/" + remotePath
    _, err := client.R().SetFile(filepath.Base(localPath),localPath).
        SetHeader("Content-Type", contentType).Put(uri)
```

None work.

Comment: Been using Go since late 2018 and never had any need for a third party library for HTTP in Go, why don't you try the default http client ?

Answer (score 0):

`SetFileReader` and `SetFile` are both intended to be used for multipart uploads.

`SetBody` is the right function to use, but I believe you need to read in the file contents first and then pass the bytes to `SetBody`:

```
uri := "/artifactory/" + remotePath
    data, err := os.ReadFile(localPath)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    _, err = client.R().SetBody(data).
        SetHeader("Content-Type", contentType).Put(uri)
```